# How to remove "selected" border around GtkButton?

Tags: gtk

In GTK+, how to remove this dotted border around a GtkButton, which gets drawn after we click the button?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the "focus" indicator. To get rid of this, remove support for keyboard-controlled focus from the button, like this:

```
GTK_WIDGET_UNSET_FLAGS(GTK_WIDGET(button), GTK_WIDGET_CAN_FOCUS);
```

Comment: The API has changed since this answer was posted: "GTK_WIDGET_CAN_FOCUS has been deprecated since version 2.20 and should not be used in newly-written code. Use gtk_widget_get_can_focus() instead."

Comment: but.. what if you want to support focus, but still get rid of the button, for design reasons?